# Android new project app crashes in debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, crash, project, release

I just created a new empty project in Android Studio, and right away ran the app on my phone - it worked perfectly fine. But when I debug the project, it crashes as soon as the breakpoint reaches the end of the code.

Here's the code:

```
package app.harc.zhp.delete2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Could anyone help, or at least try to debug a new project on Android Studio 2.2 and tell if it's any different?

Everything is fine on a Virtual Device though.

Log:

```
10-06 23:43:52.029 D/DefContainer(32406): Copying /data/local/tmp/app.harc.zhp.delete2 to base.apk

10-06 23:43:52.466 I/PackageManager.DexOptimizer(894): Running dexopt (dex2oat) on: /data/app/vmdl735784381.tmp/base.apk pkg=app.harc.zhp.delete2 isa=arm vmSafeMode=false debuggable=true oatDir = /data/app/vmdl735784381.tmp/oat bootComplete=true

10-06 23:43:52.670 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=-1: uninstall pkg

10-06 23:43:52.845 I/PackageManager(894): Package app.harc.zhp.delete2 codePath changed from /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-1 to /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2; Retaining data and using new

10-06 23:43:52.845 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=-1: replace pkg

10-06 23:43:52.846 W/PackageManager(894): Code path for app.harc.zhp.delete2 changing from /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-1 to /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2

10-06 23:43:52.846 W/PackageManager(894): Resource path for app.harc.zhp.delete2 changing from /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-1 to /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2

10-06 23:43:53.242 W/PackageManager(894): Couldn't remove dex file for package:  at location /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-1/base.apk, retcode=-1

10-06 23:43:53.254 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=0: pkg removed

10-06 23:43:54.974 E/Drive.UninstallOperation(1390): Package still installed app.harc.zhp.delete2

10-06 23:43:55.261 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=-1: set debug app

10-06 23:43:55.262 I/ActivityManager(894): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0

10-06 23:43:55.591 I/ActivityManager(894): Start proc 32594:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 for activity app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity

10-06 23:43:55.659 W/ActivityThread(32594): Application app.harc.zhp.delete2 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...

10-06 23:43:57.327 W/System  (32594): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:43:57.332 I/InstantRun(32594): Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.harc.zhp.delete2, real application class is null.

10-06 23:43:58.147 I/Finsky  (22410): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.PermissionPolicies$PermissionPolicyService.onStartCommand(117): post-install permissions check for app.harc.zhp.delete2

10-06 23:43:58.158 I/Finsky  (22410): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.bn.run(1302): Package state data is missing for app.harc.zhp.delete2

10-06 23:43:58.368 W/System  (32594): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:43:59.414 V/ApplicationReceiver:onReceive(32675): 2016-10-06 21:43:59-null-ApplicationReceiver detectes the installation of package:app.harc.zhp.delete2 ver:1.2.0

10-06 23:43:59.509 I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi(31885): Updating corpora: APPS=app.harc.zhp.delete2, CONTACTS=MAYBE

10-06 23:44:02.550 D/OnUpgrade(585): onReceive --- > package name (data string): package:app.harc.zhp.delete2

10-06 23:44:34.162 I/ActivityManager(894): Process app.harc.zhp.delete2 (pid 32594) has died

10-06 23:44:34.201 I/ActivityManager(894): Start proc 1898:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 for activity app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity

10-06 23:44:34.332 W/System  (1898): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:44:34.334 I/InstantRun(1898): Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.harc.zhp.delete2, real application class is null.

10-06 23:44:34.493 W/System  (1898): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:44:35.208 I/ActivityManager(894): Displayed app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity: +39s636ms

10-06 23:44:35.594 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=0: from pid 1895

10-06 23:44:35.594 I/ActivityManager(894): Killing 1898:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 (adj 0): stop app.harc.zhp.delete2

10-06 23:44:35.606 I/WindowState(894): WIN DEATH: Window{92da02e u0 app.harc.zhp.delete2/app.harc.zhp.delete2.MainActivity}

10-06 23:44:35.694 W/ActivityManager(894): Force removing ActivityRecord{5907531 u0 app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity t2575}: app died, no saved state

10-06 23:44:35.726 W/ActivityManager(894): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{984b1eb 0:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166}, curProc for 1898: null

10-06 23:44:44.631 I/ActivityManager(894): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10070 on display 0

10-06 23:44:44.700 I/ActivityManager(894): Start proc 2259:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 for activity app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity

10-06 23:44:44.853 W/System  (2259): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:44:44.861 I/InstantRun(2259): Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.harc.zhp.delete2, real application class is null.

10-06 23:44:45.085 W/System  (2259): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:44:45.774 I/ActivityManager(894): Displayed app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity: +1s100ms

10-06 23:44:48.343 I/WindowState(894): WIN DEATH: Window{cded2e4 u0 app.harc.zhp.delete2/app.harc.zhp.delete2.MainActivity EXITING}

10-06 23:44:48.383 I/ActivityManager(894): Process app.harc.zhp.delete2 (pid 2259) has died

10-06 23:45:20.869 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=-1: set debug app

10-06 23:45:20.869 I/ActivityManager(894): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0

10-06 23:45:20.909 I/ActivityManager(894): Start proc 3464:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 for activity app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity

10-06 23:45:20.963 W/ActivityThread(3464): Application app.harc.zhp.delete2 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...

10-06 23:45:22.785 W/System  (3464): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:45:22.790 I/InstantRun(3464): Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.harc.zhp.delete2, real application class is null.

10-06 23:45:22.971 W/System  (3464): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:45:39.892 I/ActivityManager(894): Process app.harc.zhp.delete2 (pid 3464) has died

10-06 23:45:39.931 I/ActivityManager(894): Start proc 3892:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 for activity app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity

10-06 23:45:40.016 W/System  (3892): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:45:40.021 I/InstantRun(3892): Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.harc.zhp.delete2, real application class is null.

10-06 23:45:40.166 W/System  (3892): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:45:40.845 I/ActivityManager(894): Displayed app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity: +19s949ms

10-06 23:45:40.931 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=0: from pid 3889

10-06 23:45:40.931 I/ActivityManager(894): Killing 3892:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 (adj 0): stop app.harc.zhp.delete2

10-06 23:45:40.946 I/WindowState(894): WIN DEATH: Window{39b6bfc u0 app.harc.zhp.delete2/app.harc.zhp.delete2.MainActivity}

10-06 23:45:40.983 W/ActivityManager(894): Force removing ActivityRecord{2ef5a72 u0 app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity t2577}: app died, no saved state

10-06 23:45:40.992 W/ActivityManager(894): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{481683 0:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166}, curProc for 3892: null

10-06 23:46:02.406 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=-1: set debug app

10-06 23:46:02.406 I/ActivityManager(894): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0

10-06 23:46:02.425 I/ActivityManager(894): Start proc 4463:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 for activity app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity

10-06 23:46:02.473 W/ActivityThread(4463): Application app.harc.zhp.delete2 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...

10-06 23:46:04.288 W/System  (4463): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:46:04.291 I/InstantRun(4463): Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.harc.zhp.delete2, real application class is null.

10-06 23:46:04.533 W/System  (4463): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:46:31.003 I/ActivityManager(894): Process app.harc.zhp.delete2 (pid 4463) has died

10-06 23:46:31.021 I/ActivityManager(894): Start proc 4979:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 for activity app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity

10-06 23:46:31.113 W/System  (4979): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:46:31.115 I/InstantRun(4979): Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.harc.zhp.delete2, real application class is null.

10-06 23:46:31.297 W/System  (4979): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.harc.zhp.delete2-2/lib/arm

10-06 23:46:31.882 I/ActivityManager(894): Displayed app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity: +29s467ms

10-06 23:46:31.996 I/ActivityManager(894): Force stopping app.harc.zhp.delete2 appid=10166 user=0: from pid 4992

10-06 23:46:31.996 I/ActivityManager(894): Killing 4979:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166 (adj 0): stop app.harc.zhp.delete2

10-06 23:46:32.011 I/WindowState(894): WIN DEATH: Window{7271944 u0 app.harc.zhp.delete2/app.harc.zhp.delete2.MainActivity}

10-06 23:46:32.083 W/ActivityManager(894): Force removing ActivityRecord{b4396be u0 app.harc.zhp.delete2/.MainActivity t2578}: app died, no saved state

10-06 23:46:32.098 W/ActivityManager(894): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{dabc29 0:app.harc.zhp.delete2/u0a166}, curProc for 4979: null
```

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: You should look through the logcat top find the stacktrace for an exception. It will help a lot if you use the filtering tools in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

add   this in dependencies  --
                  'compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

and  also add below code in application class --

```
    MultiDex.install(this);
```